# how to update windows 10 in specific hours only

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I want to force windows to only use certain hours for downloading the updates. I want it to be between 3 AM and 7 AM. Windows can download at that interval but not in any other hours. How can I force windows to automatically start checking for updates and download them in those hours?

Answer (score 2):

In order to change this, you will have to use group policies. This is obvious in a domain, but if your computer is not in a domain, you can still change the group policies locally by searching for `gpedit.msc` in the startmenu.

You will want to go to the following branch:

```
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows updates
```

Find the setting `Configure Automatic Update` Enable the policy, and then you can set the time. It will execute as a manual update check. First see if there are updates, then download them, then install them and depending on other settings there, it will or will not reboot if necessary optionally by a delay specified.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Control panel > all control panel items > windows update > change settings, and set updating to 3:00am!

hope it helped!

Comment: That is not the answer. Because that setting has nothing to do about when it downloads updates. It only schedules when not to restart the device !!!